# Добавить точки перед заглавными буквами

Tags: java

Нужно убрать лишние пробелы и добавить точки перед заглавными.
Пробую так:

```
String str = " Один пробел  Два пробела   Три пробела    ";
String str2 = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
String str3 = str2.replaceAll("\\s[А-ЯЁ]", ". ");
```

Смущает, что остается пробел в начале. Ну ок, допустим удалю его точечно. А вот с точками беда.

```
 Один пробел  Два пробела   Три пробела    
 Один пробел Два пробела Три пробела 
. дин пробел. ва пробела. ри пробела
```

Как бы мне это сделать, пожалуйста, подскажите.

Comment: positive lookahead `"\\s(?=[А-ЯЁ])"`

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = " Один пробел  Два пробела   Три пробела    ";
str = str.trim()
     .replaceAll("\\s+", " ")
     .replaceAll("\\s([А-ЯЁ])", ". $1");
```